# c# xaml how to define global object for all the pages in the app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have a ten pages and i want to define this object:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
```

for all the pages in the app, not to write this in each page.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to have many instances of Stopwatch or one instance for all application. In last case you need add this code to App.xaml.cs:

```
    private static Stopwatch _stopwatch = null;
    public static Stopwatch  Stopwatch 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_stopwatch == null)
                _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            return _stopwatch;
        }
        set { }
    }
```

Here I have created private instance of the class and method to get this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Singleton pattern. Please refer link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```